# how do I calculate total accumulative bull / bear candles for the session?

Tags: pine-script

Hi I am trying to plot the total number of bull and bear candles for the session but can figure out how to get it to start at open each day and then add these up as the day progresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but results can change dependant on if you have extended session data on or not, so I have used a non-repainting security call to pull down the daily open price from the bar prior. Then we can check for a change in that value which will only happen at the daily session open no matter your timeframe (if below daily). This change detection we can use to zero our counter, and then just add one if we are in session and see a candle meeting our description.

```
//@version=5

indicator("Blake Makes It Count")

htfopen = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])[barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]

var bullish  = 0
var bearish  = 0

if ta.change(htfopen)
    bullish  := 0
    bearish  := 0

if session.ismarket and close[1] > open[1]
    bullish += 1
if session.ismarket and close[1] < open[1]
    bearish += 1
    
plot(bullish)
plot(bearish)
```

Cheers and have a great day

Comment: Thank you Bjorgum. I love the title. I think im going to call my first album that :)