# I am trying to workout how I sum up all the open / closes on a given day of both bull and bear candles

Tags: pine-script

Hi I am trying to amend some code to enable me to be able to sum up the total bull and total bear candle sizes as the day has gone on however I am having no luck with the below code

The 11th line is coming back with the following issue

Variable 'bullish' was declared with 'series int' type. Cannot assign it expression of type 'series float'.

```
htfopen = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])[barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]

var bullish  = 0
var bearish  = 0

if ta.change(htfopen)
    bullish  := 0
    bearish  := 0

if session.ismarket and bullish
    bullish += open-close
if session.ismarket and bearish
    bearish += close- open

plot((bullish/2),color=color.lime, linewidth=2)
plot((bearish/2),color=color.red, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I calculate total accumulative bull / bear candles for the session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69506823/how-do-i-calculate-total-accumulative-bull-bear-candles-for-the-session)

Comment: Unfortunately no as that was my original question which I have done what I need to with however when trying to amend the code that its sums up size rather than count each one, its throwing issues up

Comment: Please [edit] this (or that) question, and add some sample input, to create a [mre].   Please also specify the issues, because how can anyone help you with the issues when they are not known ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to the declaration of your variables at the beginning as they are integers rather than floating point variables. Pine is strict on the definition of these 2 as there are many instances where we would not want to one to be the other or unintended results could occur. Try changing the var bullish and bearish declarations to 0.0 rather than 0 at the beginning and that should clear it up for you. There’s 2 options here

var bullish = 0.0

We can add the decimal or we can tell pine it’s type designation like this

var float bullish = 0

var float bullish = na

var float bullish = 0.0

This way any of the 3 will work. (Remember this if you ever want to declare a variable as na)

Cheers

Comment: brilliant, thank you Bjorgum. really handy to know.